# Why works wrong the angular filter?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

[PictureFilter](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/view/160412/787863173Untitled_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)
Angular's filter not works correctly, as you see in the picture, for seach 'shi' it is also find the abc-sea , nnnn-road row...

I tried with this:

```
<div flex="30">
            <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
            <table class="table table-hover" id="shipmentTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                            shipment name
                            <i ng-show="sortType == 'name' && !sortReverse"
                               class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
                            <i ng-show="sortType == 'name' && sortReverse"
                               class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'transportMode'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                            transport mode
                            <i ng-show="sortType == 'transportMode' && !sortReverse"
                               class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
                            <i ng-show="sortType == 'transportMode' && sortReverse"
                               class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="member">
                <tr ng-class='{selected: $index==selectedRow}'
                    ng-click="selectRow($index);getSelected(shipment);"
                    ng-repeat="shipment in shipments | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchText">
                    <td>{{shipment.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{shipment.transportMode}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

But its not working correctly....what can be  a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you filter searching for contains in through out the object `shipment`, so current filter filter has `shi` somewhere there in there property. Do apply filter on specific `property` of object like `{name: searchText}`,

```
ng-repeat="shipment in shipments | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:{name:searchText}"
```